# Stop generation of TestResult.xml with NUnit GUI test runner

Tags: xml, unit-testing, nunit

Is it possible to stop the generation of **TestResult.xml** when using the **NUnit GUI test runner**, or to change the location that it is saved to?

At the moment, it is always saving to the same directory as the nunit project file, and I can't seem to alter the behaviour. (Probably brain-freeze on my part.)

I am using the latest release of **NUnit V2.5.7**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like this is possible, but there is a discussion thread about being able to do this in version 2.6.0 here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunitv2/+bug/697069

Perhaps you could add your $0.02 to the feature request over there and get the behaviour that you need.

I'm sure you are aware you can manually save your test results as XML to any folder via the Tools Menu, but that just saves a second copy where you want it to go and does not suppress the creation of the XML file in the first place.